# How to iterate properties of a generic type?

Tags: typescript

I need to see if a given string matches any of the properties of a class.

```
export class FooBar<t> {
    checkIfStringIsParameter(value:string):boolean{
        return value in t;
    }
}
```

I understand that `t` needs to be an entity instead of a type, but when I try to create an empty instance of `t`, all the parameters are stripped because they aren't initialized.

Is there a way to do this without creating a fully constructed instance of `t`?

Comment: You'll either need a value of type `t` or an array of all the keys of `t`.  Those will not happen automatically; you'll have to make them yourself with JavaScript code (i.e., TypeScript code at the value level, not at the type level).

Comment: @jcalz the other day I seen you posted an answer with type inference through function types + conditional types. Wouldn't some of those black magic help here too?

Comment: You can infer types from values but not the other way around. The type system is erased during transpilation; by the time values exist at runtime, the static types are gone.  So `return value in t` requires `t` to be a runtime value with all the keys you care about; what the OP is calling a "fully constructed instance".  Or it can be changed to `return keys.includes(value)` where `keys` is an array containing all the keys, but that array will need to be built and passed in somewhere. Maybe with a more fleshed-out use case and a [mcve] I could suggest something else, but who knows ‍♂️